# Batch Upscale ISO images

Tags: dvd, batch, iso-image

I have most of my DVD collection ripped to ISO (just the movie, not the rest) I have loads of storage space, but an underpowered PC running boxee.

I'd like to convert all the ISO images into upscaled versions of themselves. What's the best way to go about this? I've got about 200 images in all, so I'd really like this to be a batch processed job that I don't have to manually feed each file to.

Comment: What operating system are you running Boxee on?  It makes a big difference as to what tools are available to you.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: If it was Linux I'd recommend a chain of commands including such things as mencoder, dvd-author, and more.  I know mencoder is available for Windows, but I don't know about the others.  (mencoder is part of mplayer)

Answer (score 1):

Browsing on phone at the moment but will put links in later. Not sure what container or codec you're going for as end result but would advise a chain involving:

- AnyDVD (or equivalent)
- [DGindex](http://neuron2.net/dgmpgdec/dgmpgdec.html)
- [AviSynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page)
- [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)

You could automate relatively easily as both AnyDVD and DGindex support command line switches andavisynth scripts are just txt files with an .avs extentsion. Can't remember if MeGUI supports CLI, but it does allow queuing. Alternatively, swap MeGUI for [x264](http://x264.nl/) and that supports CLI (and I find results are better).

EDIT: Back on PC now. The AviSynth script you want will be:

```
Spline36Resize([Width],[Height])
```

720p frame size is 1280x720. The goal with resizing is to maximize either width (widescreen films) or height (fullscreen films) for the desired resolution while keeping the Aspect Ratio as close to the source as possible (never lower). The equation for this is fairly simple:

[image]

For instance, I have a source which is (688,560). I would therefore end up with the following if I wanted to resize/upscale:

[image]

My final .avs would therefore be for a 720p encode (after rounding down to nearest even):

```
Spline36Resize(1280,1040)
```