# How do I change a video file's dimensions to transfer it to a portable device?

Tags: windows-xp, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to play some Xvid video files on a Creative Zen MX.

According to Wikipedia, "Video must not exceed the player's dimensions at 320 × 240 pixels".

What software can I use to convert the video down in dimensions? I'm having trouble Googling for a solution because I'm not sure as to the correct terminology - downscale, convert, shrink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

My suggestion would be to use that one. It's available for Windows, OS X and Linux as well. It's free, open-source, supports threading and relies on the popular ffmpeg video codec library.

You can of course [adjust the size](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/PictureSettings#size) of the output video, but if you're lazy you can probably also use one of its built-in presets. There are probably some for 320x240 since it's a standardized video resolution typically found in mobile devices.

If you go manual, your main settings will be:

- Video - Video codec: MPEG-4 (ffmpeg)
- Video - Framerate: Same as source
- Picture Settings - Size (see picture below, something like this)

[image]

Note that the window could look different for Windows. You can also check the result with a preview window to make sure that there is no distortion.

---

#### [SUPER©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)

This is a free Windows only tool that also wraps the ffmpeg codec library into a GUI. It therefore has the same features, but I find the interface rather ugly and the workflow is not as polished.

The settings should roughly be the same. For the output codec, choose MPEG-4. Under Video Scale Size, choose 320x240.

[Here at the bottom of the page is the download link](http://www.erightsoft.com/S6Kg1.html), just for convenience because it's really really hard to find on the website and direct links don't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at both. Am I going mad or is there no download link for Super? Its site just goes round in circles directing me to other things...

Comment: @bcmcfc Yeah, the site's kinda.. well.. I added the link at the bottom of my answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the process I described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/242365/batch-upscale-iso-images/265881#265881) for Windows using AviSynth in response to another question for changing the size of video files. What programme you use for the encoding is really up to you. A couple of options (in order of personal preference):

- [X264](http://x264.nl/)
- [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)
- Handbrake (detailed below)

Answer (score 1):

The tools I've used are Handbrake, SUPER and [XmediaRecode](http://www.xmedia-recode.de/download.html). all will do what you want.
In XmediaRecode there are pre-sets for various devices including some of the Zen models.